# Bevel tool refuses to add edges to model

Tags: bevel, tools

today I wanted to add some edges to my model, but unfortunately the bevel tool doesn't bevel properly.

[image]

This is the result I get with it affecting edges only.

[image]

While this happens when I make it affect vertices only.

I have never had this issue before. I tried applying scale and rotation, but nothing seems to be fixing this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some of the face normals are inverted on your object. Check the <kbd>Face Orientation</kbd> option on the <kbd>Viewport Overlays</kbd> menu and faces with inverted normals will be shown in red.

[image]

Go into Edit mode, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all then <kbd>Shift-N</kbd> to recalculate the normals and your bevel tool will work correctly.

Comment: I've begun to adopt [John Dickinson's](https://www.youtube.com/@Motionworks) habit  of assigning pleasant modelling colours to the 'Face Orientation', and leaving it switched on all the time.

Comment: I've just stuck it on the Quick menu. That way you can instantly access it in either Object or Edit mode without having to search for it in different places on the overlay menu.

Comment: Yes. That's. Annoying. Trivial fix, almost worth an RCS.

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by not having applied scale, for example.

To apply the scale, choose your 3D object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>, and click on *Scale*.

Comment: I tried applying the scale but the issue is still there.

Comment: I have attached a photo with my Bevel settings. Perhaps you can try copying them and that way you might be able to see which setting was problematic.

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/996001987252469843/1127263232692854784/Screenshot_2023-07-08_183921.png

Comment: I tried copying the settings but unfortunately my issue was not fixed.

Comment: Some of the faces of your object have inverted normals. Select All in Edit mode and Shift-N to recalculate them.

Comment: Oh that worked! Thanks.